# Blurred / semi-transparent background in rich iOS10-notification's ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios10, unnotificationrequest

I'm working on [advance notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/) in **iOS 10** for our app and have been asked by our designer, if I can do **blurred/semi-transparent background** for `ViewController`'s part (like on the image below):

[image]

As you can see - behind the kitten it's possible to distinguish icons below the notification.

I've been trying some dummy ideas like set `View`'s background to `Clear` (or semi-transparent color), etc. - but nothing worked.

**Is it feasible?** If yes - how can it be implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't UIBlurEffect be enough to do this?

Comment: @matt can you help me to understand? I've added as a blurred `subview`, but the root `view` of notification content extension still has white background => blurred view is being shown on top of solid white view.. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably you're not missing anything; it sounds like the view that the system is putting up on your behalf just isn't under your control. If the system gives it a white background, and won't let you change that, then there's probably nothing you can do about it.